# client-side url mapping

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using express and I'd like to clean up my hard-coded URLs. There seem to be a number of projects which produce urlFor functionality on the server-side. Is there a best practice for doing this on the client-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a shared module which exports two functions: `pathRaw`, and `pathFor`.

`pathRaw` outputs a path which can be consumed by the express routing mechanism. For example:

```
pathRaw('user.video.new');
```

returns `'/users/:userid/videos/new'`. Note that I'm using the pluralization functionality from mongoose.

`pathFor` takes the output from `pathRaw` and replaces the ids. For example:

```
pathFor('user.message.index', {userid: 'u1'});
```

returns `'/users/u1/messages'`. Note that additional values are converted to query parameters.

There are a few other features like path overrides that I've added. I'll probably put this up on github once the code is a little more battle tested.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work for you?

https://gist.github.com/4108452